# DNS browsing history by date

Tags: dns, powershell, history, browsing

I found this Powershell script online,

```
@echo off
Powershell -noexit "ipconfig /displaydns | select-string 'Record Name' | foreach-object { $_.ToString().Split(' ')[-1]   } | Sort | Out-Gridview"
```

Is there a way to make this script display the date of the DNS history?

Comment: What "browser" are you talking about since there's IE, Firefox and Chrome to name a few? Have you seen https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-export-the-history-b3245ae7 or http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ie_cache_viewer.html

Comment: No, i'm talking about the history from dns. I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758108(v=ws.10).aspx and a quick test using just `ipconfig /displaydns` from command line, it does not keep any date or time stamp information in those entries in order for you to modify the Powerhhell query to bring back up results.

> /displaydns | The command to display a client resolver cache.
>
> The **ipconfig /displaydns** command provides you with a means to view the
>   contents of the DNS client resolver cache, which includes entries
>   preloaded from the local Hosts file, as well as any recently obtained
>   resource records for name queries resolved by the system. This
>   information is used by the DNS Client service to quickly resolve
>   frequently queried names before it queries its configured DNS servers.